# Convert varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime

i'm trying to convert following varchar date to datetime format but it doesn't work

```
select Convert(datetime, '2010-04-14',103)+10 AS DocDueDate
from tblActionHeader AH
```

i'm getting the error

```
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

Comment: SQL Server takes the 14 in 2010-04-14 to be the month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a date style for the format dd/mm/yyyy, use the style 120 instead:

```
select Convert(datetime, '2010-04-14',120) + 10 AS DocDueDate
from tblActionHeader AH
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a cast, as "select cast('2010-04-14' as datetime)"?

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
create table test2 (updatetime varchar(20));

insert into test2 values ('2010-9-12 10:33:5');

select updatetime from test2 where convert(datetime,updatetime,110)>'2010-9-12
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using style 103, you should be using British French Date formatting.

```
select DATEADD(Day, 10,Convert(datetime, '14/04/2010',103)) AS DocDueDate
```

See [the docs for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).